# How can I add 10 lines from a file (file2) to another one after 2 lines (file1)?

Tags: text-processing

I have two different files separated by `Tab`. File 1 looks like this:

```
transcr_15824   3.95253441295071    3.99992738843234    3.93880798313547
YML042W 10.3143219248979    10.6898819949325    11.0073811719421
transcr_18545   7.76182774638543    7.25508954643215    7.92562682485731
YCR105W 8.46144110056843    8.30995100411912    8.85470858413405
transcr_18545   7.76182774638543    7.25508954643215    7.92562682485731
YMR325W 6.2822794040082 6.46992587787936    7.00507748994596
```

File 2 looks like this:

```
YLR177W 11.321823973245 12.1264440368589    11.7777091957438
YOR117W 10.7514234580732    11.3932687209745    11.2587694561818
TY_120  5.95114867088525    5.93580053538449    5.89166059690558
YMR174C 8.49545850099485    8.72467418433346    9.6518559706269
YPL117C 10.7211879012765    10.5046713289602    10.6145538571844
TY2_LTR_77  11.9297940548212    11.9801206538102    12.049127298122
YOL101C 7.76141097131674    9.89522697916433    7.85466704627526
YLR053C 7.62843998411388    7.49205634213499    7.10263942962051
YBR135W 9.70614244227352    9.3114074341804 9.36413815370247
YNL168C 9.93928326709444    10.3036524361223    10.0704544058998
```

What I'm trying to do right now is to add 10 lines from `File 2` to `File 1` after 2 lines. It should look like this:

```
transcr_15824   3.95253441295071    3.99992738843234    3.93880798313547
YML042W 10.3143219248979    10.6898819949325    11.0073811719421
YLR177W 11.321823973245 12.1264440368589    11.7777091957438
YOR117W 10.7514234580732    11.3932687209745    11.2587694561818
TY_120  5.95114867088525    5.93580053538449    5.89166059690558
YMR174C 8.49545850099485    8.72467418433346    9.6518559706269
YPL117C 10.7211879012765    10.5046713289602    10.6145538571844
TY2_LTR_77  11.9297940548212    11.9801206538102    12.049127298122
YOL101C 7.76141097131674    9.89522697916433    7.85466704627526
YLR053C 7.62843998411388    7.49205634213499    7.10263942962051
YBR135W 9.70614244227352    9.3114074341804 9.36413815370247
YNL168C 9.93928326709444    10.3036524361223    10.0704544058998
transcr_18545   7.76182774638543    7.25508954643215    7.92562682485731
YCR105W 8.46144110056843    8.30995100411912    8.85470858413405
```

So, basically, I'm trying to move 10 lines from `File 2` between each `transcr_` keeping the already existent line that is already below each `transcr_`.

Edit:

`File 2` has around 2,000 lines and `File 1` has around 200 "transcr_" rows. So, it would be: pick up the first 10 lines of `File 2`, put them between the first and the second "transcr_" rows (and after the already existing line between those two "transcr_". Then, get the lines from 11 to 20 from `File 2` and put them between the second and the third "transcr_". Then, get the lines from 21 to 30 from `File 2` and put them between the third and the fourth "transcr_" and so on.

It may look like this:

```
transcr_1
already existing line
10 first lines from `File 2`
transcr_2
already existing line
Lines 11-20 from `File 2`
transcr_3
already existing line
Lines 21-30 from `File 2`
transcr_4
.....
```

Comment: Welcome on U&L! Have you got only two files, or more files like `File 2` to be merged into `File 1`? Should the whole content of `File 2` be added to `File 1`? Or a part of it only? Should the content of `File 2` be added after a specific occurrence of `transcr_`, or after all of them?

Comment: there are three "transcr_" lines in file1; do you want the same 10 lines from file2 after each of those transcr_ lines, or ... subsequent 10 lines from file2 each time, or ???

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I need the subsequent 10 lines from file 2. File 2 has more than 2,000 lines

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I need the subsequent 10 lines from file 2. File 2 has more than 2,000 lines. I would need the first ten rows of `File 2` to be moved between 1st transcr_ and 2nd transcr_, then the next 10 to be moved between 2nd transcr_ and 3rd transcr_ and so on

Comment: Hi @LucasFarinazzoMarques. Please edit your question to include what you're actually trying to achieve. Currently, your question seems like it has an answer.

Comment: Do the "transcr_" lines match up between the files? The first one seems to, but the second one, `transcr_18545`, is repeated in file1.

Comment: Just edited the question to be more clear! Sorry for my mistake

Comment: @JeffSchaller, yes, some transcr_ do repeat. I don't have any "transcr_" on file 2, just rows with other genomic names

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use `ed`!

```
ed -s file1 <<< $'2r !head -10 file2\nw\nq'
```

This tells ed to edit file1 with three commands:

1. on line 2, read in the output of the command `head -10 file2` and insert it
2. `w`rite the file out
3. `q`uit ed

With GNU sed (using the `e` extension, which pipes input from a shell command):

```
sed -i '3e head -10 file2' file1
```

---

### Extended solution, to iterate through file2

The script below is a `for` loop that repeats the `ed` idea as many times as there are `transcr_` blocks in file1. Each time through the loop, we calculate three items:

1. the line number for `ed` to start reading from file1
2. the line number for `sed` to start reading from file2
3. the line number for `sed` to stop reading from file2

Item #1 is spelled out more clearly as: `10*(N-1) + 2*N`, which I reduced to `12*N - 10`.

Items #2 and #3 are spelled out more clearly as `10*(N-1) + 1` through `10*N`, which I reduced to `10*N - 9` through `10*N`.

I replaced the `head` command with the more flexible & powerful `sed` command for picking out blocks of lines from file2.

This will rewrite file1 `times` times as it goes through the loop.

```
# how many times we need to insert blocks
times=$(grep -c transcr_ file1)
for((index=1;index <= times; index++));
do
  printf "%dr !sed -n %d,%dp file2\nw\nq\n" $((12 * index - 10)) $((10 * index - 9)) $(( 10 * index ))  |
    ed -s file1
done
```

Comment: Hey there Jeff! Thanks for your answer!
Both worked for the first iteration. Do you know how can I replicate it for the whole File 2? It has at least 2,000 rows and I would need the first ten rows to be moved between transcr_1 and transcr_2, then the next 10 to be moved between transcr_2 and transcr_3 and so on

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding; see if the update gets you closer; thanks!